# Partial derivatives in a variable name

Tags: symbols, variable

I would like to create variable with names of the form `\[PartialD]g` and `\[PartialD]\[PartialD]g`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "Prefix operator *with built-in evaluation rules*." (emphasis mine) as written [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/PartialD.html) pretty much precludes it from being part of a symbol (look at the result of `LetterQ["\[PartialD]"]` as well).

Comment: Thank you, that's a pity!

Comment: @J.M.:  That looks like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest using any of the other similar-looking characters:

- U+1D6DB
- U+1D715
- U+1D74F
- U+1D789
- U+1D7C3

all of which seem to produce a valid symbol in Mathematica.

[image: Partials]

Comment: I particularly like the second one.

Comment: This is ideal. How do I write these in Mathematica?

Comment: @Jonathan, to use the second one as an example, you can input it as `\|01d715`.

Comment: When I write \|01d715 and then g (with no space) it seems to alter the first character to something strange.

Comment: StringJoin["\|01d715","g"] gives a big gap between the two characters. I've been unable to get rid of this space.

Comment: @JonathanShock, yes, you can see the same thing happening on my image above. It seems like Mathematica has some troubles with correct kerning for non-standard Unicode characters. I don't know from the top of my head whether this can be fixed.

Comment: It wasn't just the kerning, for me, the character is completely corrupted (possibly missing fonts?). The partial derivative becomes a sort of "A" in a box.

Comment: It would be best to show some screnshot. Is it something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUoF1.gif)? Mathematica also has troubles with multibyte characters, that is why you can actually delete half of the character .

Comment: It looks like this: http://13.244.252.124/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Screenshot-2021-12-16-at-16.54.33.png

Comment: Does it look the same if you copy the characters from my answer? Is it the same for all of them? Which operating system and Mathematica version are you using?

Comment: Yep, the same. I'm using 12.3.1.0 on MacOS 11.6.